# Django - Division of two specific fields in queryset

Tags: django

I am trying to get the lead conversion rate, by dividing the two fields in a queryset (lead_count and client_count)

Here is the query

```
qs = CustomerInformation.objects.filter(salesDepartment=department).filter(created_date__range=(start,end))
qs = qs.annotate(date=TruncYear('created_date')).values('date').annotate(lead_count=Count('status',filter=Q(status="lead")), client_count=Count('status',filter=Q(status="client")))
```

Is there any way to divide the field 'client_count' by the field 'lead_count' to obtain conversion rate?

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use [**`F()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression with [**`ExpressionWrapper`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations).

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, FloatField

qs = qs.annotate(conversion_rate=ExpressionWrapper(F('client_count') * 1.0 / F('lead_count'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried doing that, but the conversion rate returned was 0 even though my client count was 2 and my lead count was 4, which should return 0.5 for the conversion rate. I tried to flip the calculation to lead_count / client_count and it returned conversion_rate = 2 as expected, so i guess the issue now is the rounding off, is there any way to overcome that?

Comment: okay i solved it by adding a *1.0 after the F('client_count') to adjust it to a float, i read it somewhere, and apparently if both fields in the F expression are integers, the division result would be an integer even if the output field is defined, hence i switched it to a float before dividing and it worked! thanks so much for your help :-)